# Hosting a VirtualBox machine on a router

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-network

I am on a project whilst England is in lockdown to keep me from going insane, but this one is driving me more insane, please help??

I've set up a PC server running Ubuntu with 5 network devices (one on mobo, 4 more on a pci-e card) and routing between all 5 works fine.

What I want to do now though is run a VirtualBox (or two) on the host machine and bridge in the virtualbox devices into the working switch I have created.

My idea is create a TAPx or TUNx interface on the host which it's client vm can use to connect to. Currently the VM gets an IP from the host's isc-dhcp-server, however from there there is no more communication. No ping, no, nothing... Just it's IP address.

I'd like to share a few NFS shares to the virtualbox servers, and have one virtualbox running mariadb connecting to another virtualbox that needs to communicate with it. There needs to be communication between the physical connections and the virtual machines.

I have tried TAP interfaces & TUN interfaces on the host to bind the VM's to, but I am stuck. They get an IP from DHCP, but no more traffic.

Firewalld on or off, no difference.

Has anyone done this, and could you please suggest a solution as I want to figure out this problem whilst in lockdown to learn more about networking stack in Linux and kernel networking.

Many, Many thanks in Advance,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, that's exactly what this setting is for:

[image]

(The screenshot is on Windows because I happen to have it handy, but it's the same UI on all platforms.  I also have VBox on my Lubuntu partition, so I can dual boot and still run the same VM's.)

My setting as shown is specifically to keep that VM *off* of the internet while the host is still online.  You might want to play with the NAT and Bridged options instead.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for the reply. I've been looking at host only and have 'played' with it, but unsuccessfully. I'm trying to attach eth0 in the VM to tap0 or tun0 on the host, then add the tap or tun interface into the config for br0 alongside the physical eth interfaces. So the VM looks like just another machine attached to the network switch. Am I making sense?

Comment: @Bon Almost, but not really.  I've never had so many separate network interfaces on one machine, with so many different names.  (eth, tun, tap, br, etc.)  It suggests to me that they may have different configurations with different capabilities that can't be guessed by the name alone.  Also, your usage of the term "switch" is ambiguous in this context because the machine that you're running this on *is* a switch, whereas the default definition of that term is an external, dedicated device.  See what sub-options you have under the two that I suggested.  Maybe one of them will do what you need?